# How Can I export my large list's items into excel or CSV vertically

Tags: python, r, excel, list, stack

**My input is:**
[image: input]
I used **ffff= unstack(df)** function to unstack my two-column data, but the result is a **large list** as shown in the picture:[image: large list]

I'm struggling with finding a proper way to export my data into CSV or Excel file would you please help me?
There are 2462 lists and their names are hsa-let-7a-2-35 and .... I want them to be column names and their values under them. For example my desired output is:
[image: I want to export like this]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but perhaps you just want to transpose the df and write it to csv? Like `ffff.T.to_csv('your_filename.csv')` ?

Comment: well Yes I want to transpose my data, to be more clear, I want the values of the first column to be my variable names and the second column items to be variables observations, I attach my input data you can have a look please

Comment: It seems like creating a Pivot Table with no aggregation would turn your original data into your desired result.  How is your original data stored?  In Excel, you can easily do this using Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the lengths in an `lapply` will let you put `ffff` into a `data.frame`, which is easy to write out to a .csv:

```
data.table::fwrite(data.frame(lapply(ffff, `length<-`, max(lengths(ffff)))))
```

With example data for `ffff`:

```
set.seed(94)
# create a list of vectors of different lengths to use as an example
ffff <- setNames(lapply(sample(1:10, 8), function(x) sample(1:100, x)), LETTERS[1:8])
# make the vectors all the same length and write out to csv
data.table::fwrite(data.frame(lapply(ffff, `length<-`, max(lengths(ffff)))))
#> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
#> 87,61,57,92,38,14,29,100
#> 15,43,36,16,49,76,92,33
#> ,75,19,10,40,7,8,25
#> ,92,71,100,89,65,90,
#> ,87,55,76,,69,20,
#> ,33,91,65,,54,98,
#> ,55,93,,,83,36,
#> ,,97,,,5,58,
#> ,,33,,,,40,
#> ,,,,,,63,
```